# Add new column to the existing table based on specific row value conditions

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

For the below table sample, I want to add  and additional column lets say " Amount difference" and it should have value  only if   the successive rows of D column has "Success" and "Waiting" as value and A B and c column value matches exactly.  IN such scenario the new coulmn  F (Amount difference) should have (15-0) as the value and rest of the column values should be null.  If the successive rows doenst have Waiting then the value of row 2 in New column should be 15 and rest all rows should be null.

| A Id | B session Id | C customer Type | D ticket status | E Amount | ORDINAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | A | vip | Failed | 10 | 0 |
| First | B | ordinary | Success | 15 | 1 |
| First | B | ordinary | Waiting | 0 | 2 |

How can this be achieved with a query please?

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result. I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: How are you ordering your rows so that you know which are successive rows? The rows in a table have no intrinsic order

Comment: The rows are already ordered by an ordinal column. But we many not know which at which ordered number the success and waiting will be coming . But lets consider 3 rows for now which is already ordered.

Comment: The data needs a column by which to order the rows before anyone can provide an answer (assuming you want an answer that is written in SQL rather than just a description of a possible solution)

Comment: I have added the ordinal column which can be used for ordering